# C accessing another programs memory?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I wrote this code so I can see the address of variable foo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

char* foo=(char*) malloc(1);
*foo='s';
printf(" foo addr : %p\n\n" ,&foo);
int pause;

scanf("%d",&pause);
return 0;

}
```

Then pause it and use the address of foo in here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
char * ptr=(char *)0x7ffebbd57fc8; //this was the output from the first code
printf("\n\n\n\n%c\n\n\n",*ptr);
}
```

but I keep getting segmentation fault. Why is this code not working?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch.: Why would it fix that?

Comment: On modern multi-taskin systems processes have separate memory maps. The location of something in one process might not be the same in another. Not even if the processes are running the same program. This is one of the main points of *virtual memory*.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude: "modern"? VM has been around since I was a teenager, and sadly that was not just yesterday. And the point of VM is that memory belonging to one process is not mapped to anorher process at all; its physical address is not relevant.

Comment: @rici.: The thing is - one can't be sure that memory it printed is going to be in the process's address space next time. Whether it is beloging to other process or simply not used because due to the memory allocation logic - the thing is doing this will be undefined behavior.

Comment: @coderredoc: you can be sure that it is *not* going to be mapped into some other process' memory. Yes, reading a random address is UB but it is also important to understand how VM works to isolate processes from each other.

Comment: @rici.: How can you be sure? Because you will say that memory management will never let you  point to something that is out of it's process's memory limits? Confirm it. (That's what I precisely said - that every process's memory access is controlled my MMU which consists of Base address and another limit register which will limit the access of other segment's memory.) Here it simply tried to access some of that - and it is trapped.

Comment: @coderredoc: that's not how VM works. That explanation may have been valid for DOS (which did not use virtual memory) but it is not useful for understanding operating systems in common use in this century.

Comment: @rici.: Yes I am aware - modern times each process contains it's own page table that basically keeps trackk of which pages are in the process's memory address space. What I am trying to say - that yes being aware how a simple system would prevent put of bound access of memory, modern vm will do soemthing that will result in the same behavior as above. It's not that we are trying to acess other processes memory and modifying it's content - it's about that this acess generates a trap due to out pf memory acess - here it resulted in seg fault.

Answer (score 1):

Oups, your problem is not related to C language, but really depends of the OS, if any.

First let us read it from a pure C language point of view:

```
char * ptr=(char *)0x7ffebbd57fc8;
```

your are converting an unsigned integer to a `char *`. As you get the integer value from the other program, you can be sure that is has an acceptable range, so you indeed get a pointer pointing to that address. As it is a char * pointer, you can use it to read the byte representation of any object that will lie at that address. Still fine until there. But common systems use virtual addresses and limit each process to access only its own pages, so *by default* a process cannot access the memory of another process. In addition, with the common usage of virtual memory, there are no reasons that any two non kernel processes share common addresses. Exceptions for real addresses are:

- real memory OS (MS/DOS and derivatives like FreeDOS, CP/M, and other anthic systems)
- kernel mode: the kernel can access the whole memory of the system - who could load your program?
- special functions: some OS provide special API to let one process read the memory of another one (Windows does), but it not as simple as directly reading an address...

As I assume that you are not in any of the first two cases, nothing is mapped at that address *from the current process*, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a C question/problem but a matter of runtime support. On most OS programs run in a virtual environment, especially concerning their memory space. In such case memory is a virtual memory which means that when a program access a given address *x* the real (physical) memory is computed as *f(x)*. *f* is a function implemented by the OS to ensure that a given process (object which represent the running of a code in the OS) have its own reserved memory separated from memory dedicated to other processes. This is called **virtual memory**.

Answer (score 0):

On systems use virtual memory, you have a range of logical addresses that are available to user processes. These address ranges are subdivided into units called PAGES whose size depends upon the processor (512b to 1MB).

Pages are not valid until they are mapped into the process. The operating system will have system calls that allow the application to map pages. If you try to access a page that is not valid you get some kind of exception.

While the operating system only allocates memory pages, applications are used to calls, such as malloc(), that allocate memory blocks of arbitrary sizes.

Behind the scenes, malloc() is mapping pages (ie making them valid) to create a pool of memory that is uses to return small amounts of memory.

When you omit your malloc(), the memory is not being mapped.

Note that each process has its own range of logical addresses. One process's page containing 0x7ffebbd57fc8 is likely to be mapped to a different physical page frame than another process's 0x7ffebbd57fc8. If that were not the case, one user could muck with another. (There is always a range of addresses shared by all processes but this is can only be accessed in kernel mode.)

Your problem is further complicated by the fact that many systems these days randomly map processes to different locations in the logical address space. On such systems you could run your first program multiple times and get different addresses.

> Why is this code not working?

You would need to call the system service on your operating system that maps memory into the process and make the page containing 0x7ffebbd57fc8 accessible.